Sqlite database locked using node js
Insert data in sqlite database concurrently uisng node js.
How to insert data in sqlite database concurrently using node js considering 10000 records per seconds.Issue im facing is of database locked if alreday database is in write mode and some data comes at that time to write in db. Npm library used is node-sqlite3. Even other api process is reading from the same file multiple time.
Is there any way to insert records at faster rate using node js in batches. Because row by row insertion is very slow.

From SQLite documentation: "SQLite supports an unlimited number of simultaneous readers, but it will only allow one writer at any instant in time."
